# read text on browsed page

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am currently very new when it comes to c# and I am trying to write a small application.
The section that I am having the issue with is this:

```
string webPageSourceCode = webBrowser1.DocumentText;

if (webPageSourceCode.Contains("Account disabled"))
{
       log.Items.Add("This account is banned RIP");
       log.SelectedIndex = log.Items.Count - 1; 
       showLoginFormAgainTimer.Stop();
       webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -= LoadAccount;
       return;
}
```

This code is meant to read a webpage to see if there is any text there that says 'Account disabled', But isn't finding it.

I have already searched around here and other places, but everytime I do all I get is info on reading text files, not reading text on a webpage

A screenshot of the webpage I'm attempting to read is here: http://prntscr.com/3ggind

Comment: insert a breakpoint after the initializing of `webPageSourceCode` and see what it contains.

Comment: @JackJack on which event is this code running? are you sure this event works?

Comment: @JackJack What is the name of the event? i didn't ask for the parameters ;) is it 'DocumentCompleted'?

Comment: @JackJack did you already check what the webPageSourceCode string contains?

Comment: Or use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com)  to see the actual http content that is sent.

Comment: @JoJo is this what you're looking for? http://prntscr.com/3ggu6h

Comment: No, the value of `webpageSourceCode` is needed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdakzs26.aspx

Comment: @JackJack ok, that is the breakpoint. now run the program, it will exit when it reaches the breakpoint, then click here 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu6PL.png (see link) that is the value of webPageSourceCode.